# How to differentiate between successful and failed delete in Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

The response returned from delete operation on any of the resources (bucket, object,etc) is always null, may it for success or failed deletion. Even when i pass bucket name which does not exist, it returns me data as {} which is also returned in case of successful deletion. There is no statusCode given along with the response indicating the state.

So, is there any way to differentiate between a successful and failed delete operation on S3 resources of amazon?

Comment: failed will have one of the error responses: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html

Comment: @AkberIqbal i had tried giving bucket name which does not exists, with request params well formed. In such case also it gave response with data = {}. I agree that if the params passed are not well formed we get malformed error, but this is case with data that does not even exist.

Comment: can you share some code? maybe you're returning {} without waiting for the async response (which might come later)

Comment: Which SDK/language are you using?

Comment: Here is an example, where my bucket bucket12345 does not have object with key 678 but still this is returning me deletemarker and versionId. var params = {
  Bucket: 'bucket12345', 
  Key: '678'
 };
 s3.deleteObject(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
   /* OUTPUT-
{ DeleteMarker: true,
  VersionId: 'dY1svi6qomrasqrCM4YABLnl8abVgqnh' }
   */
 });

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am using aws-sdk javascript sdk

Comment: @JohnRotenstein any inputs?